# menu de contexto personalizado recuperando id da tabela

Tags: jquery, html, css, context-menu

Bom galera estou tentando montar um menu de contexto personalizado que ira funcionar dentro de uma tabela de cadastro. O problema e que preciso pegar o ID que esta dentro de cada linha () e chamar ele no link do menu (Editar.php?id=).

Segue o meu código para vocês verem como esta ficando.

```js
    window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
        $('.rightclickmenu').css({
            "margin-left": e.clientX,
            "margin-top": e.clientY
        }).show();

        e.preventDefault();
        window.addEventListener('click', function () {
            $('.rightclickmenu').hide();
        });
    });
```

```css
<style>
    .rightclickmenu {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
        font: 11px sans-serif;
        display:none;
    }
    #rightclickobject {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    #rightclickobject:hover {
        background:#eee;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td id='1'>ID:1</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Idade</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id='2'>ID:2</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Idade</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="rightclickmenu">
    <div id="rightclickobject" onclick="window.open('Editar.php?id=')">Editar</div>
    <div id="rightclickobject" onclick="window.open('Apagar.php?id=')">Apagar</div>
</div>
```

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Você não teria que adicionar um checkbox para indicar qual linha você ia querer alterar ou apagar? Dai você poderia ler o ID do checkbox que estivesse selecionado

Comment: bom, acho melhor uma lista e qual clicar co o botão direito em uma determinada linha ele captura o id. e mais simples

Comment: Então coloca uma mesma classe pra todos e utiliza um evento click para capturar os ID's. E o que quiser passar de dados pode utilizar jQuery.post().

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso usando o meu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro utilizei a função contextmenu da documentação do JQuery e chamei ela dentro do contexto da TR desta forma voce tem em mãos como pegar o ID referente à TR clicada. Quando o menu de contexto for ativado de dentro da tabela, forço o stopPropagation para evitar que o evento do Window seja chamado e perca a referencia para a linha e consequentemente o ID desejado.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('tr').contextmenu(function(e){
        var jqTR = $(this);

      var idTarget = jqTR.find('td:first').prop('id');

      $('#rightclickobjectEditar').off('click');
        $('#rightclickobjectEditar').on('click',function(){
        window.open('Editar.php?id=' + idTarget);
      });

      $('#rightclickobjectApagar').off('click');
        $('#rightclickobjectApagar').on('click',function(){
        window.open('Apagar.php?id=' + idTarget);
      });

      $('.rightclickmenu').css({
        "margin-left": e.clientX,
        "margin-top": e.clientY
        }).show();

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

Foi necessário tambem modificar o id do "rightclickobject" pois estavam dois com o mesmo nome e id deverá ter apenas um nome para todo o documento.

```
<div class="rightclickmenu">
    <div id="rightclickobjectEditar">Editar</div>
    <div id="rightclickobjectApagar">Apagar</div>
</div>
```

Segue abaixo o JSFiddle da solução

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/85LgtuwL/)

Comment: muito bom, como faço para gerar uma div pai para cada <tr> da tabela?

Comment: Como assim, gerar um div pai, o TR é um elemento que só tem como parent um TBODY / THEAD / TFOOT ou TABLE

Comment: ok muito obrigado pela ajuda :)